# Probability of an event happening over period of time with $100 \%$ certainty, calculating the probability of lesser intervals.

Tags: probability

If I have a certain event that is $100 \%$ to happen **exactly once** in $10$ days, how can I calculate the probability each day?

I cannot be $10 \%$ per day, since by the end of $10$ days, there still would be a $0.9^{10}$ chance of the event not happening. It can't be $100 \%$ per day either, since that would mean the event happens $10$ times.

What if for smaller and smaller intervals? What's the probability of the event happening in $10$ minutes, $1$ second? $1$ nanosecond?

Comment: After 9 days with the event not happening, the probability of it happening on thetneth day is not 10% but 100%. By the very assumptions about the event, the 1-day subevents are not independent. -- So, if  we at least boldly assuming uniformity, the probability is indeed just proportinal to the length of the subinterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability each day is 10%, the probability of the event happening on the 10th day is still 10%, the probability that you calculated is a conditional probability.
If we call $A_i$={the event happen the i day}.

{the event happen the 10th day knowing that it had not happen the 9 day before} = $\{A_{10}|\cap_{i=1}^{i=9} A_i^\complement \}$
We can calculate
$$
P(A_{10}|\cap_{i=1}^{i=9} A_i^\complement )=\frac{P(A_{10}\cap (\cap A_i^\complement))}{P(\cap A_i^\complement)}=1
$$